# I cannot get the appearance of the body to be shiny in photoviewer 360

Tags: solidworks

I want my object to look like so:

[image]

I have tried many things including selecting different metals, changing the setting to shiny, changing the scene & more, but it always ends up looking like the following:

[image]

This is what happens when I hit final render when brushed chromium is selected:

[image]

Comment: For something to reflect you need it to exist in your setup. Either add some objects around or use an environment texture.

Comment: Flat surfaces, in general, dont look very exciting when rendered reflective, you need curves for that to happen.

Comment: the edges are curved, although that's only a small part.

Comment: Put a 360 Photosphere around it. That will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render the image to have it as you want. Unfortunately rendering option is not available in the student edition, therefore if your is a student edition there is no way to obtain that effect, no matter the material you assign.

If it is not a student version look for the rendering command. It could take from few seconds to even hours to render the image according to its size and complexity. In your case it will not take long

Comment: it is not a Student edition but it is a trial version. I do have the photoview 360 feature. As you can see in the first picture I have all the options available. I just added another picture to show what happens when I hit on final render when I selected brushed chromium as the metal. It looks nothing like the examples. I'm not sure what Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

go into the appearance options where you can add cameras and lights and make sure your lights are set to "on in photoview 360".  That drove me insane for a long while before I figured out that's why my renders came out so dull looking.  If they're still not bright and shiny enough add another light and focus it the way you want it and do a low quality render to see if it's giving the effect you want before you let it render for hours on one of the higher quality settings.

Answer (score 0):

Everything about reflectivity is about setting environment, but there are couple of parameters with which you can make your part gloss or matt… But in this situation its environment…

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please visit the [tour] and [help] for more about how our site works. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.